# VB6. DataEnvironment: How to Configure/Set Trusted Connection?

Tags: vb6, database-connection

I have a DataEnvironment component in my VB 6 application. I cant configure the DataEnvironment connection to use trusted connection without ask me how to connect. I could set prompt to never appear, but it doesnt connect becouse it doesnt use trusted.

In this link you could see the screens of DataEnvironment Connection Options and the prompt.

[Google Presentation Link](http://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dpzvk4h_29d8hg59dp)

I need this program to be executed from a D.O.S console without prompt anything.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Trusted do you mean you want to connect using Windows Authentication? 
If so how about adding `;Integrated Security=SSPI` to your `ConnectionSource`?

Comment: Also i found that if you do right click over CN object in the DataEnvironment design, you will found a lot of configuration opcions. Trusted Connection (Integrated Security=SSPI) included.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to do it in code:
See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195982

```
DataEnvironment1.Connection1.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptNever.
```

Comment: Thanks Bard but my problem was how to set trusted connection. Sorry if becouse my english you dont understand me. The prompt could be set to never appear as i had say in my question message.